# cakephp - how to route to the homepage with an argument

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-2.x

I'm a bit new to cakephp and having trouble figuring out how the routes work. I've read the docs and tried a few things but I'm wondering now if the way it's all set up means it impossible to do with cake.

So I have an app and the majority of users who visit it will be interested in one page only. So i'd like this page (payments/select) to be the one which people end up on when they visit the root of my domain.

```
    Router::connect(
        '/', 
        array('controller' => 'payments', 'action' => 'select')
    );
```

The above works fine but I want to pass an argument to this action too. But if I put an * beside the /

```
    Router::connect(
        '/*', 
        array('controller' => 'payments', 'action' => 'select')
    );
```

Then if I want to visit users/login for example it maps to payments/select/users/login.

How can I make it so that all other controllers and actions go where they're supposed to but if the user visits the homepage with a parameter they go where I want them?

Do I need to write routes for each controller? Seems excessive if there's loads of them so I wonder if there's a more correct, cake, way.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`*` is catch-all, so that's the expected result, it will catch everything. If you really need to catch arbitrary arguments, then you'll have to move that route definition underneath all other routes (it's first come first served), and make sure that the above routes are specific enough so that the catch-all route can be reached.

If you don't need to accept arbitrary arguments, and/or you cannot move the route further down the pipe, then define an actual route element and restrict it so that the route only matches on the very type of argument that you need, either using a regeular expression:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:elementName', 
    array('controller' => 'payments', 'action' => 'select'),
    array('elementName' => '\d+') // argument must be a number
);
```

or by using a custom route class, where you can apply whatever logic you need.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Development > Routing > Connecting Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes)**
- **[Cookbook > Development > Routing > Connecting Routes > Route Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements)**
- **[Cookbook > Development > Routing > Custom Route Classes](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes)**